# Continuity not routing audio properly for calls

Tags: macos, facetime, continuity

I just set up my new Mac/iPhone combo, and am having trouble getting phone calls via continuity to work properly.

I can both initiate and answer phone calls from the Mac, and the status popup shows correctly, and allows me to control the call. However, as soon as the call connects (either incoming or outgoing) the audio only comes out of the iPhone. This happens regardless of whether I am attempting to use the computer's internal mike/speakers or my attached Bluetooth headset.

I suspect that I am missing a setting somewhere, but have no idea where to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW - If I have Settings > General > Accessibility > Call Audio Routing > Set to speaker (nice when using 'Hey Siri' to make a phone call; to have it auto default to speaker phone) My phone and continuity crashes on me.  So I need it set to "Automatic" and it works fine. Took me forever to figure this out.

Not sure if this is applicable to your problem or not but hope it can help you or someone.